# ScrollView memory issue by adding .content - SwiftUi

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, offset, lazyvgrid

For populating ScrollView with a large amount of data, apple is suggesting using LazyVGrid inside the ScrollView: [LazyVGrid - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid)

So this sample code that is loading 500 random photos works perfectly in case of memory management: (Almost 30MB).

I used [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) as image loader.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible())]) {
            ForEach(1...500, id: \.self) { value in
                KFImage(URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/800/800?\(value)"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But I want to have a controll over the content of ScrollView, like offset.
So as soon as I added `.content.offset(y: 5)` the memory goes up to **640MB** !!

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible())]) {
            ForEach(1...500, id: \.self) { value in
                KFImage(URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/800/800?\(value)"))
            }
        }
    }
    .content.offset(y: 5)
}
```

[image]

Is there any reason behind the `.content`?!! How can I handle not having a large amount of memory?
I need to disable scroll and control content offset manually, not by using `ScrollViewReader`.

Thanks

Comment: try switching to `AsyncImage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be accessing the `content` of a `ScrollView` outside a `ScrollView`. If you want to modify the content, simply add the modifications to the body of the `ScrollView`.

If you are accessing `content` outside the `ScrollView`, SwiftUI has to calculate `content` 2x - once inside the `content` closure of the `ScrollView` and again when accessed from outside the `ScrollView`. This also breaks the lazy-loading of lazy grids as stacks, since the layout system cannot detect what parts of the view are currently visible, so it has to load the whole view into memory.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible())]) {
            ForEach(1...500, id: \.self) { value in
                KFImage(URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/800/800?\(value)"))
            }
        }
            .offset(y: 5)
    }
}
```